# How to clone an app in 2022?

Tags: applications

So, I tried to clone an app but it didn't work. My goal is to have an application with 2 different versions installed on the same smartphone, without using additional applications such as Parallel Space.

On the old version of the app, I was able to do it normally using Lucky Patcher(LP). But on the latest version of the app, I failed to use LP to clone the app. Then, I tried to kill signature verification before cloning, but that didn't work either. Then I tried killing signature verification using MT Manager and re-signing it before putting it in LP, but it didn't work either.

On LP, it shows the application has been cloned successfully. However when I open it, the app is like force close before fully opening.
How to do it? Did I miss something?

Answer (score 1):

Lucky Patcher tends to not work on newer apps. Your best option would be apps like [Parallel Space](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lbe.parallel.intl) or a phone/custom ROM with that functionality built-in.

Comment: It's alright. I've done it.

Answer (score 0):

It's resolved now. I have no idea why using LP sometimes it's not work on a specific app.

I used the APK Editor app to solve this problem. By going through killing signature verification and changing the package name a bit.